# Matrix solutions and nonsigularity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singularity

I'm new to matrices and have some trouble with them, if anyone can help me with the next question I would appreciate it a lot.

Let A be a 3x3 matrix and suppose that 
$2a_1 + a_2 + 4a_3 = 0$

a. How many solutions will the system Ax=0 have?

b. Is A nonsingular?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you clarify the relationship between $a$ and $A$?

Comment: If in a.) the answer is not 1, then A is singular.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_i$ refers to the $i$-th row of $A$.

$$2a_1+a_2+4a_3=0$$

implies that the rows are linearly dependent which implies that $A$ is singular and $Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do you know they are linearly dependent? I think it has something to do with the determinant right?

Comment: we know $\{ a_1, a_2, a_3\}$ is linearly dependent if we can find non-trivial solution for $c_1a_1+c_2a_2+c_3a_3=0$. Can you identify the $c_i$?

Answer (score 0):

It means $u = (2,1,4)^\top$ is a solution of $Ax=0$.As are all scalar multiples $\alpha u$. So we have infinite many solutions.

Non-singular matrices have only the null vector as solution of $Ax=0$, which is not the case for this matrix.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but why the transpose? and what doe scalar multiple $αu$ mean?

Comment: To have $u$ be a column vector, which is the more common case,  and compatible with $Ax=0$. For row vectors it would be $xA =0$. The scalars depend on the vector space you have. If it is over the reals then each real multiple of the vector $u$, e.g. $-4u$ is a solution of the homogeneous system as well.